# RSpec undefined controller method AFTER explicit controller declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In spec\controllers\signups_controller_spec.rb I have the following code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SignupsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "new - it creates a new signup at @signup" do
    get :new
    assigns(:signup).should be_a_new(Signup)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Just to double check pluralization issues, my controller is indeed SignupsController.

Anyways, I added the type declaration per other answers, because I was getting the error of undefined method 'get' that I'm still getting. Any thoughts?

```
C:/Sites/GoogleTest/spec/controllers/signups_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `get' for #<Class:0x4eaa748> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the common way to structure your specs:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SignupsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET new" do
    it "creates a new signup at @signup" do
      get :new
      assigns(:signup).should be_a_new(Signup)
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Refer to the [official documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking at samples, and it's very easy to get caught up in a world of describe and forget the tiny nuances.